# python "local variable referenced before assignment" with hundreds of threads

Tags: python, multithreading

I am having a problem with a piece of code that is executed inside a thread in python. Everything works fine until I start using more than 100 or 150 threads, then I get the following error in several threads:

```
    resp.read(1)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'resp' referenced before assignment.
```

The code is the following:

```
    try:
        resp = self.opener.open(request)
        code = 200
    except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
        code = e.code
        #print e.reason,_url
        #sys.stdout.flush()
    except urllib2.URLError as e:
        resp = None
        code = None

    try:
        if code:
            # ttfb (time to first byte)
            resp.read(1)
            ttfb = time.time() - start
            # ttlb (time to last byte)
            resp.read()
            ttlb = time.time() - start
        else:
            ttfb = 0
            ttlb = 0
    except httplib.IncompleteRead:
        pass
```

As you can see if "resp" is not assigned due to an exception, it should raise the exception and "code" coundn't be assigned so it couldn't enter in "resp.read(1)".

Anybody has some clue on wht it is failing? I guess it is related to scopes but I don't know how to avoid this or how to implement it differently.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 5):

Basic python: 
If there is a HttpError during the open call, resp will not be set, but code will be set to e.code in the exception handler.
Then code is tested and resp.read(1) is called.

This has nothing to do with threads directly, but maybe the high number of threads caused the HTTPError.

Comment: I think that is not correct. The HTTPError is raised when there is a response code diferent from 200, for example a 404. It works perfectly with 404 errors. Besides, it worked perfectly with thousands of requests with and without errors and and low concurrency. The connection errors wich could cause that resp is not assigned are managed by URLError afaik as they are not HTTP errors (protocol errors).   Thanks fo your response.

Comment: @user2336071 If you are sure about that, please tell me what you think is referred to as `resp` in the case of a `HTTPError`?

Comment: @user2336071 I agree with @dmeister that this is almost certainly the cause.  In particular, the only way that you can get an exception in your first `try` block is from the call to `opener.open`.  And if you do get an exception there, then `resp` will not get any value.  At any rate, it's easy enough to test -- try adding `resp=None` to the `except HTTPError` block, and see if that changes the error from `UnboundLocalError` to `AttributeError` (which you'd get when you try to access `resp.read`, where `resp==None`

Comment: @glglgl In case of HTTPError, for example a 404 Not Found, resp would be the file object containing the body and yes, a 404 can have a body.

Comment: @EdwardLoper I tried adding resp=Non inside the except HTTPError and now I get a NoneType error, so that seems to be the problem and fails with 404 HTTP Errors. But anyway I don't understand why is code=200 running when it is after an exception and mostly why with less threads the 404 HTTP Errors do not cause that behaviour.

Comment: Well, finally I found that sometimes work and sometimes not, but the propper way to get the body of an HTTPError is described here: http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml#httperror    Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @user2336071 No. In the case of a `HTTPError`, `resp` would **not be assigned at all**. `self.opener.open(request)` fails, the assignment to `resp` never happens and thus you exactly get the error mentionned.

Comment: @dmeister: **Please** pay attention when approving suggested edits 'improving' formatting. [This edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4385056) introduced a syntax error and should have been rejected (the `/` operator was deleted).

Answer (score 0):

Defining and using resp variable are not is same code block. One of them in a try/except, the other is in another try/except block. Try to merge them:

**Edited:**

```
ttfb = 0
ttlb = 0
try:
        resp = self.opener.open(request)
        code = 200
        resp.read(1)
        ttfb = time.time() - start
        resp.read()
        ttlb = time.time() - start         
     except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
        code = e.code
        #print e.reason,_url
        #sys.stdout.flush()
    except urllib2.URLError as e:
        pass
    except httplib.IncompleteRead:
        pass
```

Comment: But that is not a solution. I could also add another except for the UnboundLocalError in the second try. The problem is why the 'resp' variable is not assigned ?